# How to duplicate special multiple groups using python in maya

Tags: python, maya

I am having a question for my college assignment, in which I am creating a plane pattern using polygons, and I successfully create one line of the pattern on the x-axis and group the objects in a group, and I duplicate the group one time on the z-axis. While I have two groups now, the part of my code of duplicating the groups looks like this:

```
cmds.select(all=True)
cmds.group(name='group#')
cmds.select('group1')
cmds.duplicate('group1')
cmds.move(0.9, 0, 1.6)
cmds.select('group1','group2')
cmds.group(name='group#')
cmds.select('group3')
cmds.duplicate('group3')
cmds.move( 0, 0, 3.2 )
cmds.duplicate( st=True )
cmds.duplicate( st=True )
cmds.duplicate( st=True )
cmds.duplicate( st=True )
```

'''

So how can I simplify this code by using a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment above, if we ignore the grouping you are doing and just focus on looping, you could do something like this to create a cube-grid of poly cubes:

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds

iterations = 10
distanceIncrement = 2

for x in range(iterations-1):
    cube = cmds.polyCube()
    cmds.setAttr('{}.translate'.format(cube[0]), x*distanceIncrement, 0, 0)
    
    for y in range(iterations-1):
        cube = cmds.polyCube()
        cmds.setAttr('{}.translate'.format(cube[0]), x*distanceIncrement, y*distanceIncrement, 0)
        
        for z in range(iterations-1):
            cube = cmds.polyCube()
            cmds.setAttr('{}.translate'.format(cube[0]), x*distanceIncrement, y*distanceIncrement, z*distanceIncrement)
```

You can use the same technique of nested loops to create a variety of patterns, so hopefully this lets you work towards a solution to your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean and/or why you would want to loop. I should also point out that nearly every line you provided is different (hence, it is difficult to pick out where exactly you would like to loop). In any case, in general, if you want to loop over a set of lines with different parameters, then you need to place those parameters in a list. Likewise, if you want to loop over a set of functions, then you need to place those functions in a list. Or both. Possible example,

```
params = [(dict(all=True),      dict(name='group#'), ['group1'], ['group1'], [0.9,0,1.6]),
          (['group1','group2'], dict(name='group#'), ['group3'], ['group3'], [0,0,3.2]),
]
funcs  = [cmds.select,cmds.group,cmds.select,cmds.duplicate,cmds.move]

for param in params:
     for func in funcs:
         if isinstance(param,list):
             func(*param)
         elif isinstance(param,dict):
             func(**param)
```

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is to create a repetitive pattern in maya, while I already duplicate the polygon 20 times on the x-axis, and group these 20 duplicate objects as group1, while group2 is a duplicate of group1 on the z-axis, and I am trying to duplicate these groups on z-axis for multiple times, like 20 times. So I just don't know how can I duplicate these two groups multiple times on z-axis, with each of them having a parameter of (i * 3.2) on z-axis by using a loop.